# What's wrong with a cat who appears weak and refuses food?

Tags: cats

On the way home today I saw a stray cat crossing the road so slowly, it seemed like it didn't care if it was hit. I pulled over and tried to pick the cat and take it home but it refused and jumped off. I could feel its bones and it was very thin and feeble.

Assuming it became weak because of lack of nutrition, I went home and brought some milk in a cup but when I tried to feed it, it kept turning its face away. My second thought was to get some meat for it.

My question is what could be the reason it refused the food? What should be done in such a situation?

Comment: take the cat to a vet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reasons for such behavior can be so many that only a vet can diagnose and treat the cat.

Your idea of feeding it some some milk was nice, but absolutely detrimental! It's actually good that the cat refused to drink it.

Almost all adult animals (with the notable exception of humans) are lactose intolerant. Feeding milk or cream to cats is a popular myth, but it would cause them diarhea and discomfort. If the stray cat was malnurished and weak, diarhea would cause even more harm.

**If you find the cat again, please take her to a vet as soon as possible.**

If you're ever in a similar situation, please offer clean water and pet food (either wet food or kibbles soaked in water),  **unseasoned** cooked meat or **unseasoned** mashed potatoes. There must be absolutely no onions or garlic in the food.